# Invalid or Unsupported Image Format Recover CS50

Tags: c, image, jpeg, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // open memory card
    if(argc > 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *img;
    // repeat until end
    int i = 0;
    // 512 bytes into buffer
    uint8_t buffer[2048];
    char *filename = malloc(8);
    // if start of new jpeg
    while(fread(&buffer, 512, 4, file)) // read card
    {

        if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) // if start new jpeg
        {
            // if first
            i++;
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, img); // fixed

        }
            //else
        else
        {
            // if still reading jpeg
            if(img != NULL)
            {
                fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, img);
            }


        }




    }


    //close
    free(filename);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

I think my code is pretty close to being done but the images returned are invalid or unsupported image format. It compiles fine and it returns 12 images. I do not want to look at a solution to fix this. Where did my code mess up?

Comment: Why `char *filename = malloc(8);`? Why not `char filename[8];`?

Comment: In CS50 they mentioned this. Isnt that correct?

Comment: And when you write the output file, why do you write only a single byte?

Comment: You never `fclose` the `img`.

Comment: @g_4_vrv, it's not incorrect, but using an array is recommended since it avoids memory allocation overhead. Especially when the size is known at compile time.

Comment: That worked, but it is supposed to output 50 images.

Comment: Remember that you read `2048` bytes at a time. Perhaps you should only read `512` bytes at a time instead?

Comment: Optionally, perhaps you need to have two loops nested inside one another: The outer to read from the input file, and the inner to loop over the buffer to find the signature in multiple places in the buffer.